# Find the intervals on which it is increasing and those on which it is decreasing of the following function.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives, maxima-minima

> Find the intervals on which it is increasing and those on which it is decreasing of the following function. $$f(x)=x^3-9x^2+24x-12,0\leq x\leq 6$$

After differentiating (once) the function I get that $x=2,4$. But, I was getting confusing by reading those description of in some intervals it is increasing in some intervals it is decreasing.

> Here, symbol of $f'(x)$ is $=(-)(-)=+$ (positive) in $0\leq x<2$ interval. that means $f'(x)>0$. Hence, the function is increasing in the interval $0\leq x<2$.

I was confused for symbol/sign. They wrote $(-)(-)=+$ (positive) but, where they found those sign? If I can understand for the interval than, I can understand for other intervals also. That's why I didn't add further information.

I guess most of people may confuse for a single description. So, I am adding further information from book again.

> symbol $f'(x)$ is $=(+)(-)= negative$. That means $f'(x)<0$, hence the function is decreasing in the interval $2<x<4$

Comment: Factor the derivative and look at thge sign of each piece

Answer (score 1):

I was watching [the tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dyl7jPlJXOM). When I differentiated that function (which I wrote in question). I got

$$f'(x)=3x^2-18x+24$$

When I worked on the equation further. And, put that $f'(x)=0$ than, I got that $x=2,4$.

[image]

I wrote down intervals then.

$$0\leq x<2$$
$$2<x<4$$
$$4<x\leq6$$

I was putting values (from interval) in function then.

$$f'(x)=3(0)^2-18(0)+24$$
$$=24$$ So, the value is increasing the interval ( $[0,2)$ ) since it is positive value.

$$f'(x)=3(3)^2-18(3)+24$$
$$=-3$$

So, the value is decreasing. I will get positive value for $5$ and $6$. For that reason that is increasing.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative can be written as $f'(x)=3(x-2)(x-4)$. If you plug in a value $x<2$, then both parenthesis will be negative, so the product will be positive. That is probably what they mean with $(-)(-)=+$, but note that this is very informal notation.

Comment: I have edited my question..